# A good interpreted language for a small embedded project

Tags: programming-languages, low-level, embedded-systems

I have an [mbed microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbed_microcontroller) which has a small [ARM Cortex M3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M3#Cortex-M3) on it. Basically, my effective resources for the project are ~25 KB of RAM and ~400 KB of Flash. For I/O I'll have a [PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) keyboard, a VGA framebuffer (with character output), and an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) for saving/loading programs (up to a couple of MB maybe).

I ask because I'm trying to figure out what programming language to implement on the thing. I'm looking for an interpreted language that's easy for me to implement and won't break the bank on my resources. I also intend for this to be at least possible to write on the device itself, though the editor can be interpreted (yay, bootstrapping).

Anyway, I've looked at a few simple languages. Some nice candidates:

- [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29)
- BASIC
- [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29)?

Has anyone done something like this or know of any languages that can fit this bill or have comments about my three candidates so far?

Comment: If your scale is too small to fit LUA, you may just be stuck with C, and your own implementation of a language in it. If you can get scheme to fit then it's a great candidate for writing your own simple scripting language in.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa you're saying I should implement scheme on my device and then from there implement a scripting language in scheme? double interpretation? lol

Comment: No, I'm referring to writing an interpreter in scheme, then compiling that interpreter to native. Though I'm sure there are better compilers for scheme than this, but here's the first google pop for compiled scheme: http://matt.might.net/articles/compiling-scheme-to-c/

Comment: I'd like to add that the [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net/doc/v0.8/en_tc_cortex.html) project also has a port to ARM M3, I think it will be useful to you.

Comment: There are several Tiny Basic interpreters (some written in C), where the total memory footprint can be as little as 16kB (even less for the ones written in ASM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what you have described, FORTH is probably ideal.  FORTH routinely runs on much smaller platforms than yours.  (16K total is a big machine for FORTH.)  There is going to be some serious learning curve involved, if you've never looked at FORTH before.

There's a Scheme implementation called TinyScheme (as I recall), that might be worth a look.  I first heard about it from a piece on Slashdot, about a guy who used it as the core of his malware engine.  (Yeah, that's right: His job was writing malware, for something or other, and doing it in TinyScheme meant their payload could be a lot smaller.)

Comment: I looked at TinyScheme. I think it would work, but I don't know Scheme at all.. So, I figured Forth would be easier to wrap my head around(which it is). I wouldn't consider Forth to have an absolutely huge learning curve, I've worked with stack machines before though, so that's probably why it comes fairly natural to me heh. Forth is excellent for this though because it's trivial to extend later to do a crude form of JIT and such... and implementation consists of a stack, a dictionary, and a few built in words

Comment: So, in summary. I ended up going with writing my own (non-compliant) Forth interpreter.

Comment: Leo Brodie's classic "Starting FORTH" is by far the best introduction to FORTH I have ever found, even if it does describe a very old version of the language and environment (16-bit polyFORTH, from FORTH Inc.).  If you can find a copy, Loeliger's "Threaded Interpretive Languages" does a very good job of explaining how to implement FORTH on a Zilog Z80 microprocessor.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to make the case that [Lua](http://www.lua.org/about.html) is by far your best bet. You can compile Lua anywhere that C can run and it's one of the lightest scripting languages out there. It's massively flexible as a language and the skills are quite transferable as well. There's even a specifically embedded version of [Lua](http://www.eluaproject.net/).

Addendum: It is apparently [possible](http://www.lua.org/notes/ltn002.html) to get the memory footprint down to just over 25K.

Addendum 2 - Things get nutty: There is an option brought up by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759391/what-is-a-good-scripting-language-for-a-small-embedded-system). [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/) is a language that I've heard of but never used. It's apparently even smaller than Lua due to use of reference counting.

Comment: There is `eLua` but it's out of my range for resources. Basically 32K of RAM is required for anything useful

Comment: Lua won't ever be able to compete with Forth in footprint.

Comment: NEver said it could. Lua isn't as alien to most programmers though.

Comment: +1 for [Lua](http://www.lua.org) and [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net/).

Comment: If my processor had a bit more RAM, I'd use eLua, but unfortunately it doesn't, so I'm writing a small Forth compiler

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading some time ago about Tcl/Tk and its use in routers.

Excerpt from the "Embedded Development" paragraph found at http://www.tcl.tk/about/uses.html:

> Because Tcl is a very compact language, and is easily integrated with
>   special hardware, it is a popular choice for embedded development.
>   You'll find Tcl hidden away on many devices, including many networking
>   products from Cisco and others, and set-top boxes including Tivo.
>   Embedding Tcl within other software projects is of course also hugely
>   popular, and has become the dominant control language in some
>   industries, such as in electronic design automation (EDA) and
>   computer-aided design (CAD) applications.

Comment: You don't have to drag tk along with Tcl -- Tcl is a fine language all by itself. You might also consider "TinyTcl" - http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinytcl/

Answer (score 1):

Regarding embeddable scripting languages, the 2 I'm familiar with are [**LUA**](http://www.lua.org/about.html)  and [**PAWN**](http://www.compuphase.com/pawn/pawn.htm) .

I think there are versions of Python & other such languages ported to embedded systems, but they tend to be the embedded Linux variety. Depending on your platform (no idea if it's a little MCU with 8K ROM or an embedded PC) that might be an option.